# AJAX request is timing out with a 404 even though the file exists, seems to be requesting from a different server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache, nginx

I have a website that is using jQuery's $.post method to submit a contact form to a PHP script that processes the info and sends it via email. I have tested the script locally and it's working properly. When I try to run it on the server, the ajax request to the processing script sits as (pending) for ~3 minutes before returning a status of 404. However if I inspect the request and navigate directly to the Request URL I can see that the script is indeed there and functioning properly.

The most bizarre thing, though, is that it returns an nginx 404 error. The server is running Apache, not nginx. Also, the site has a custom 404 page that works properly if you navigate to any non-existent page.

As a first test, I created another PHP script that simply echoes a string, put it in the same location as the form processing script, and AJAX requests to that work just fine. It's only the request to the processing script that doesn't go through.

You can view the page here with the contact form and AJAX Test. http://dev.alpha1marketing.com/contact/ When you submit the contact form a loader will spin indefinitely and if you inspect the request you'll see it pending for a few minutes before returning the mysterious 404. The Ajax Test button returns the request almost immediately.

Here is the code that posts the form submission to the form processing (this doesn't work)

```
# Post the form
$.post('/wp-content/themes/alpha1/ajax/send-contact.php', {
  firstName: $.trim($('#firstName').val()),
  lastName: $.trim($('#lastName').val()),
  email: $.trim($('#emailAdress').val()),
  referral: $.trim($('#referral').val()),
  comment: $.trim($('#comment').val())
},
(response)->
  # Show some messages

  return
)
```

And here is the code that posts to the "test" script (this does work)

```
$.post('/wp-content/themes/alpha1/ajax/test.php', {
}, (response)->
  console.log response

  return
)
```

I'm fairly certain this has something to do with the server/network configuration, but I'm stumped as to what aspect of it. There's another site being developed in parallel you can view at http://dev.krasdalefoods.com/contact/, and it's having the same issue using the same form processing code.

The two dev. domains are hosted on Bluehost, and the plan is for the primary domains to move over to Bluehost once the sites are complete. The client purchased and initially configured some aspects of the server before giving me access to the control panel to set up what I needed so it's possible that something they did is causing this issue, but I'm not sure what it could be. I believe the primary www.alpha1marketing.com and www.krasdalefoods.com domains are hosted on IIS, so that couldn't be causing the nginx error either.

Any help debugging this would be appreciated!

Comment: POST /wp-content/themes/krasdale/ajax/send-contact.php is where the form is being posted to (not alpha1/ajax).  line 592 of all.js

Comment: That's true on the Krasdale site, but on the Alpha1 site I still see it going to /themes/alpha1/ properly. http://dev.krasdalefoods.com/wp-content/themes/krasdale/js/all.js vs http://dev.alpha1marketing.com/wp-content/themes/alpha1/js/all.js

Comment: If you are sure nginx isn't the middleware, its def a server config issue.

Comment: How would I go about figuring that out? All I know is that the server itself is running apache. I found some kind of "Varnish Cache" thing in the Bluehost control panel and cleared/disabled it thinking maybe it had that script cached as a 404 but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: `curl -I http://dev.alpha1marketing.com/contact/` tells me nginx is serving this site. I'd check to see where nginx is looking for files

Comment: That's incredibly bizarre. Theoretically if there was some kind of nginx caching server in between, would that explain what you're seeing? Also, why would this one request not work but the other request would work?

Comment: Also - I just did a `curl -I http://dev.alpha1marketing.com/wp-content/themes/alpha1/ajax/send-contact.php` - the file that's getting a 404, and it returned a 200 OK instead.

Comment: Check nginx config, make sure its not timing out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98007/discussion-between-ryan-giglio-and-kisaragi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the issue with nginx was a red herring. The problem was the fact that BlueHost doesn't allow you to send messages through an external SMTP server - only through theirs. I was trying to send the messages through Gmail and that request was being blocked by BlueHost, which was causing their nginx middleware to see nothing but a hung script and return a 404.

Switching my mailer script to use PHP mail() was, unfortunately, the way I had to go. It still works!